# How do I access the garden?

Tags: cookie-clicker

I unlocked a sugar lump, then used it to level up my farms, from lvl 0 to lvl 1, and it said when I lvl it up I unlocked something, so I looked up what it was because nothing happened when I lvled it up( like nothing popped up or anything like that) and found out that it unlocks something called the "Garden" and I don't know how to access the said "Garden"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Next to the upgrade button, there should be an "open garden" button that's available.
This button might only show if you choose to show the ribbon containing the farms.

See linked picture [here](https://i.redd.it/s0ttcmfl53p01.png)